# Header title remains visible beneath custom toast on top position

Tags: react-native, position, toast, react-navigation-v6

I have created a custom toast message, positioning it absolute and i want to display it on top. I am also using react navigation. But the problem is when i display the toast message, my stack header's title is still visible underneath the component. When i place the component in the center of the screen, it covers the other components but when it comes to positioning it on header, i can't get the desired view.

```
    <View style={styles.overlay}>
      <Animated.View
        entering={FadeInUp}
        exiting={FadeOutUp}
        style={styles.messageContainer}
      >
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Hi</Text>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
```

And below are my styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  messageContainer: {
    /*  
    position: "relative",
   */
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 60,
    width: 340,
    borderRadius: 12,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    elevation: 2,
  },
  contentContainer: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    marginLeft: 20,
    padding: 10,
    flex: 1,
  },
  overlay: {
    alignItems: "center",
    elevation: 1,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

What can i do to position this on top?